# "He told me that he [has/had] got temporary residence in England"

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, past-perfect

Telling a friend about another friend,

> Yesterday I met John. He told me that he has/had got temporary residence in England.

Which one is appropriate here, *has* or *had*?

Comment: 'had got' may imply that John has changed his residence again.

Comment: Use either “has” or “has got” to say he possesses it, but use “has gotten” or “had gotten” to say that he received it.

Comment: @tchrist In BE the past participle is *got*, not *gotten*. It does cause some ambiguity, because they Brits have also largely adopted the US *HAVE got* for "possess".

Comment: muhammad, you should modify your sentence to end in *temporary residence in the UK*. England is one of multiple parts of the UK.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with 'has got'. In formal speech I'd say 'has received'.

"Has got" indicates something that has happened in the recent past, but which is still ongoing. *"John has recently got temporary residence in England, and still has it at this time"*. "Had got" suggests something perhaps in the more distant past, which has now ceased to be the case. *"John had got temporary residence in England, but it was cancelled a month ago"*.

On the other hand, I would say either alternative is acceptable. It is a matter of stylistic preference and avoiding ambiguity.

Comment: +1, excellent answer, even if I disagree that there is a difference between "had got" and "has got" in reference to the time frame.

Comment: ... in fact also for a thing happened one second ago you can use "had got".

Comment: ... the difference being that that thing is relevant for the present time or not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what dialect your speaking and what you're trying to express. Right now, that's ambiguous.

If this is something that happened in the past, then it could be either *has gotten* (AmE only)/*had got* (BrE) or *has gotten/had got* depending on the circumstances and sequence of events.

If he just acquired (past) a new residence, but your not sure when, then it's **usually** *has gotten/has got.*

If he acquired a new residence and you want to signal that it was **related** to another event, then it's *had gotten/had got*

If you simply want to say that he has or possesses a new residence, then it's ***has got,*** in **both** AmE and BrE. (he's got a new residence)

The **major** difference is the tense. Strictly speaking, *has got* can **only** be used in AmE for the simple present tense (he has). In BrE you can also use the present perfect *has got* to say that he relocated at some unknown point in the past (he moved); for the present perfect  in AmE, it would be *gotten.* The past perfect *had gotten/had got* is used more to express a relationship of one event to another in the past. (e.g. Had I known that he'd gotten/got a new residence, I would have sent his birthday card to his new address)

*He told me that he had got(Br)/gotten(Am) a temporary residence <del>*of*</del> ***in*** England.*

Simple present tense is something happening now; present perfect describes an action that happened in the past at an unknown time; and past perfect indicates that something happened in the past **before** another event in the past sequentially (he told me ... he had got/gotten.

Without knowing what you intend to say, it's impossible for me to tell you which is correct.